# Recover files deleted by rdiff-backup

Tags: fedora, data-recovery, rdiff-backup

I used the following `rdiff-backup` command to backup my home directory onto a mounted drive `/run/media/me/bku`.

```
rdiff-backup -v 9 --force --include /home/me/ --exclude '**' / /run/media/me/bku
```

At the destination there were other directories and files present:

```
ls /run/media/me/bku
dir1
dir2
```

Upon completion, I noticed that all the files I had at the destination have been removed entirely.

```
2020-11-04 16:19:01.560098 -0500  <CLIENT-565010>  Removing directory /run/media/me/bku/dir1
```

Is this a normal behavior for `rdiff-backup`? Also, is there a way to recover those deleted files?

Comment: 1. Why did you use `--force`? 2. Undeleting files is hard. But there are quite a number of questions (some with answers, some marked as duplicates) addressing this here. 3. Yes it's expected behaviour: they weren't in your source so didn't belong in the backup

Comment: @roaima I put together this command a very long time ago and have been using it as such for many years, but I do not recall why I decided on `--force`.